# Spring mail: password containing invalid characters for yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, jakarta-mail

I have a password provided from outside and I have no means to change it.
Said password has a leading "@" and a "#" inside that leads to a comment.

So, the following configuration does not work:

```
spring.mail.password: @sjishi#shihs
```

is there a way to get this value from an external configuration file so I won't encounter these limitations due to yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add double quotes:

`spring.mail.password: "@sjishi#shihs"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quote.

```
spring:
  mail:
    password: '@sjishi#shihs'
```